# How do i create a dbo schema in the h2 sqlserver emulator?

Tags: scala, h2, slick

I'm getting a

```
JdbcSQLException: Schema "dbo" not found; 
SQL statement: create table "dbo"."TableName"
```

when running some boilerplate sql against the h2 sqlserver emulator (ie, with config settings:

```
db.default.slickdriver=com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver
db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:file:~/data/test1;MODE=MSSQLServer"
```

running the following:

```
Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource()) 
   withSession {
```

I've tried creating the schema:

```
  Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource())     
    withSession {
    implicit session => 
       Q.updateNA("CREATE SCHEMA \"dbo\" AUTHORIZATION sa;")
  }
```

but that doesn't seem to do the trick (or report an error message). Am I missing something?

---

still unable to create the schema programatically. was able to easily create it via the h2 console, using the exact same query as above.

---

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[JdbcSQLException: Schema "dbo" not found; SQL statement:
create table "dbo"."TestTable" ("TestTableId" CHAR(36))
at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:148) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "dbo" not found; SQL statement:
create table "dbo"."TestTable" ("TestTableId" CHAR(36))
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329) ~[h2-1.3.172.jar:1.3.172]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169) ~[h2-1.3.172.jar:1.3.172]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146) ~[h2-1.3.172.jar:1.3.172]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:613) ~[h2-1.3.172.jar:1.3.172]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:620) ~[h2-1.3.172.jar:1.3.172]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:5254) ~[h2-1.3.172.jar:1.3.172]
```

Comment: You you post the complete error message (including error code) and strack trace please?

Comment: i had a driver typo in the original code - updated my settings to reflect (and cleaned up the code some). could this be a driver issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid database URLs of this form (`jdbc:h2:file:data/test1`) as this is relative to the current working directory (and the working directory can change). Use `jdbc:h2:/absolute/path` instead, or `jdbc:h2:~/data` (relative to the current user home directory).

If you use double quotes for `create table "dbo"."TableName"`, then you also need to use double quotes for `create schema`:

```
create schema "dbo" authorization sa
```

Comment: i've tried that - Q.updateNA("CREATE SCHEMA \"dbo\" AUTHORIZATION sa;")- still seeing: Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "dbo" not found; SQL statement:
create table "dbo".

Comment: OK, I don't know what it is, because it worked for me. Are you 100% sure you create the schema with double quotes? I get the problem if I create the schema as you did in your question, but not when using double quotes.

Comment: yep - updated question to reflect my code. i'm confused, too - it works in the h2 console (ie h2-browser) but not elsewhere.